# UIPicker in Swift UI

Tags: swiftui, picker

When I add picker in form it shows me correctly to navigate on another page.But after selecting on one row it come back to previous screen and I am not able to click on it again.

Comment: Why it's one time selectable?

Comment: can you give us a reproducible code example

Answer (score 0):

I had same problem with button. It's not perfect solution, but it worked for me.
You can try add `UUID` as `@State` to your picker, and chang it when action is triggered

Like this:

```
@State private var pickerID = UUID()

... 

Picker {...}.id(self.pickerID)

... 

youAction {
.....
self.pickerID = UUID()
}
```